# Whitespace in SSRS

Tags: sql, t-sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, whitespace

I've got a part of a query that I wrote in SSRS that doesn't work like I need it to. The situation is that I'm trying to create a drop-down parameter with a list of values from a column - we'll call it Column5. The problem is that some of the rows in that column are blank; they're not null, they're just made up entirely of whitespace. Because of this, they're not showing up in the list of values for the parameter, which means those rows will be completely ignored.

What I'm trying to do is something like this:
`SELECT [...stuff...] CASE WHEN (RTRIM(LTRIM(Column5)) = '') THEN 'None' ELSE Column5 END AS ColumnAlias`

I've tried the above and a few variations on it, but nothing seems to work.

NB: I pasted the above query into SQL Server, and it worked just fine. Seems like SQL Server and SSRS deal with whitespace differently.

EDIT: Apparently part of the problem is that SQL won't filter based on a renamed column. I pasted my query into SQL Server, and included `WHERE Column5 = 'None'`. It didn't return any rows, even though there were a few thousand rows that clearly said 'None' in Column5. It seems like I might have to rethink my whole approach.

Comment: Try using NULLIF(column, '') and then filter out the NULL values.

Comment: I've tried something along those lines: `CASE WHEN (Column5 IS NOT NULL) THEN 'None' ELSE Column5 END AS ColumnAlias`. It didn't seem to work.

Comment: USe `CASE WHEN NULLIF(column5, '') IS NULL THEN 'None' ELSE column5 END`. It should work

Comment: @AgentSQL That didn't work either. It's still filtering out the blank values instead of renaming them.

Comment: If you need to replace the blank values then you can use REPLACE too. Did you try it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT [...stuff...] CASE WHEN LEFT(Column5, 1) = ' ' or RIGHT(Column5, 1) = ' ' THEN 'None' ELSE Column5 END AS ColumnAlias
```

The reason for this is that when you specify a condition, trailing spaces are ignored. In other words, "HI", "hi", and "Hi  " (with a space after it) are all considered equal.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an older post, but just in case you're still having trouble...

I've seen that empty strings or strings of spaces seem to handled and identified differently in different systems (Access vs SSRS vs T-SQL run in SSMS). I find that using the len() function works pretty well everywhere. I usually do something like the following:

```
Case 
    When ISNULL(LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM([Column5]))),0) = 0 
        Then 'None' 
        Else [Column5] 
    End
```

This way it's actively looking for and counting characters after you've removed all spacers.

Once you've identified these fields, you can put your whole query (assuming it's not overly complex) into a CTE and work with the end product. This can sometimes be easier than trying to work with the data as it is being derived.

```
With Selected_Records as (
Select ...
...
)
Select Distinct Column5

From Selected_Records
```

Then you can add any other conditions, ordering, or aggregates on top of the derived data without hindering its derivation. This works pretty well until the query in the CTE gets very complicated or utilizes many parameters (these are anecdotal observations).

Hope this helps someone.